# One one & Onto functions

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Are there one one function from the set $A$ to the set $B$?
Are there onto function from the set $A$ to the set $B$?
Where $A=\{x^2 :0<x<1\}$ and $B=\{x^3:1<x<2\}$.

Comment: Please provide us with some information on what you already got yourself, where are you struggling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $A$ is the open interval $(0,1)$ (more precisely, set a is $x:x \in (0,1)$).
Set $B$ is the open interval $(1,8)$.  The function 
$$f(A \mapsto B) | \forall z: f(z) = 7z+1$$ is both 1:1 and onto (and in fact is a bijection between those two open intervals).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $A = (0,1)$ and $B = (1,8)$. There is a bijection between any two open intervals of the real numbers; simply scale the intervals so that they have the same length, then translate.